# PHP Pass variable from foreach to function

Tags: php, mysql, function

I'm trying to pass variables from a foreach function that fetch a mysql query to an array, to another function.

I declare the array before the foreach to make it global but no data are passed to the function.
here is my code. If you have any idea of what i'm doing, thanks by advance for your help.

Of course if I replace the called function by what's inside it, everything works like a charm.
but as I'll have to use it several times I would prefer to set my variables in a function.

```
function fillStuInfos() {
        global $studFName, $studLName,c$dateStart, $dateEnd;
        $studFName = $EventsGt['fName'];
        $studLName = $EventsGt['lName'];
        $dateStart = $EventsGt['startDate'];
        $dateEnd = $EventsGt['endDate'];
}

$email = $_POST['email'];

$EventsGt = array();

$getEventsQry = 'SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Email_Company = "'.$email.'" ORDER BY startDate';
        foreach ($bddPDO->query($getEventsQry) as $EventsGt) {
                $intCur =  date_diff(date_create($today), date_create($EventsGt['endDate']));
                $intFut =  date_diff(date_create($today), date_create($EventsGt['startDate']));
                echo intval($intCur->format('%r%a'));
                if (intval($intCur->format('%r%a')) <= 4 && intval($intCur->format('%r%a')) > 0 ) {
                        fillStuInfos();
                } else if ( intval($intFut->format('%r%a')) <= 4 && intval($intFut->format('%r%a')) > 0 ){
                        fillStuInfos();
                } else {
                        echo 'No Datas!';
                        exit();
                }
        }

echo $studLName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget that exists `global` and pass params to function.

```
function fillStuInfos($data) {
        $studFName = $data['fName'];
        $studLName = $data['lName'];
        $dateStart = $data['startDate'];
        $dateEnd = $data['endDate'];
}
...
foreach (...) {
    if (intval($intCur->format('%r%a')) <= 4 && intval($intCur->format('%r%a')) > 0 ) {
        fillStuInfos($EventsGt);
    } else if ( intval($intFut->format('%r%a')) <= 4 && intval($intFut->format('%r%a')) > 0 ){
        fillStuInfos($EventsGt);
    } else {
        echo 'No Datas!';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: So evident, sometimes I forgot essentials !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your variable you want to be global is `$EventsGt`, not `$studFName, $studLName, $dateStart, $dateEnd`

With that said, I would recommend passing the event array as a parameter or passing the individual values as parameters instead.

Comment: So evident, sometimes I forgot essentials !! Thanks